# Issue with scroll follow

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a sort of sidebar on my website, which has to scroll down together with the user so that it is always in the view.

I used jquery.scrollFollow.js (http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/)

The code I'm using now is actually working fine however there is one problem. On smaller screens the sidebar scrolls before you can see the end of sidebar(because the height of this sidebar) this making it impossible to see it all.

So what I want is the sidebar to scroll with the bottom as relative point instead of top so that when you reach the end of the sidebar it starts to scroll.

thanks in advances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use CSS?

CSS:

```
div { position: fixed; bottom: 10px; right; 10px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div>My sidebar</div>
```

Comment: because I will loose that following effect obtain with jquery
and more that that ... on small screen position fixed will not resolve my issue (that sidebar will remain in same position even his height is bigger then screen view)